# Plotting multiple data sets on the same figure with 2 y axes

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I want to add a third data set to a scatterplot but it has values orders of magnitude larger than the other two data sets.

Is there a way to plot values from all three data sets in one window, signifying data set 3's y values on the right y-axis (axis 4) in a color matching the color I use for set 3's points? Here is what I've tried:

```
plot(xlab = "Mb", ylab = "Pi", 
      x, yAll,          pch = 6,  cex = .5, col = "blue", type ="b" )
lines(x, yAll_filtered, pch = 18, cex = .5, col = "red",  type = "b")
```

This gets me two of the three data sets plotted, then I don't know the next step.

Ideally I can plot set 3 values in green and have the differently scaled y values appear on the right, also in green. Basically, plotting these Y values with these parameters met

```
plot(x, yAll_normalized, pch = 19, cex = .5, col = "green", type = "b", 
     axis(4))
```

Comment: It would really help if you created a small reproducible example. Try creating a small dataset with y values of different magnitudes. Then use `dput` on the data, so we can just cut and paste it into our consoles.

Comment: Duplicate? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another

Comment: That's a good catch, @Henrik, but I suspect ggplot2 is not what the OP is after; it's rather advanced & requires a different way of thinking, whereas I suspect the OP is new to R.

Answer (score 1):

Three simple options:

`pracma::plotyy`
`graphics::axis`

Just scale your dataset before plotting.

If you go with number two, first plot your "left-hand" data the usual way, then call `axis(side=4,{other setup arguments})` followed with  `lines(data3,...)`

Edit - per gung's valid comment, here's part of the help file for `plotyy` :

```
plotyy(x1, y1, x2, y2, gridp = TRUE, box.col = "grey",
                       type = "l", lwd = 1, lty = 1,
                       xlab = "x", ylab = "y", main = "",
                       col.y1 = "navy", col.y2 = "maroon", ...)
Arguments

x1, x2  
x-coordinates for the curves

y1, y2  
the y-values, with ordinates y1 left, y2 right.

type    
type of the curves, line or points (for both data).
```

That will plot the `x1,y1` with autoscaling on the left-y axis, and `x2,y2` similarly on the right-y axis.

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'pracma'

Comment: @martingordy  Now, really!  Then go D/L it from CRAN.

Comment: +1, but I suspect your answer is too terse. I think the OP is new to R & needs a more detailed overview of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

(This question may be better migrated to stats.SE, because the issue isn't what function to call but understanding the *ideas* behind these things.)

The basic strategy here is to scale your dataset before plotting, as @Carl Witthoft notes.  Here's how it works (to understand any of the functions used, enter `?<function name>` at the prompt on your R console):

```
# here I generate some example data, set.seed makes it reproducible
set.seed(33)
x <- 1:20; y0 <- 20; y1 <- 25; y2 <- 300
for(i in 2:20){
  y0 <- c(y0, y0[i-1]+rnorm(1, mean=0.25, sd=1.5))
  y1 <- c(y1, y1[i-1]+rnorm(1, mean=0,    sd=1))
  y2 <- c(y2, y2[i-1]+rnorm(1, mean=-10,  sd=5))
}
max(y0, y1)  
# [1] 35.3668
min(y0, y1)
# [1] 17.77653
# from 0 to 50 seems like a reasonable Y range for the plotting area

windows()
  plot (x, y0, pch=6,  cex=.5, col="blue", type="b", 
        xlab="Mb", ylab="Pi", ylim=c(0, 50))
  lines(x, y1, pch=18, cex=.5, col="red",  type="b")

# We need to create a new variable that will fit within this plotting area
y2new <- scale(y2)        # this makes y2 have mean 0 & sd 1
y2new <- y2new*sd(y0)     # now its sd will equal that of y0
y2new <- y2new+mean(y0)   # now its mean will also equal that of y0

  lines(x, y2new, pch=24, cex=.5, col="green", type="b")

# now y2 fits within the window, but we need an axis which must map the 
#   plotted points to the original values

summary(y0)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   17.78   20.64   24.34   25.62   30.25   35.37
summary(y2)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   125.1   178.2   222.2   220.0   266.3   300.0
sd(y0)
# [1] 5.627629
sd(y2)
#[1] 54.76167

# thus, we need an axis w/ 25.62 showing 220 instead, & where 5.63 higher
#   shows 54.76 higher instead

increments <- (mean(y0)-seq(from=0, to=50, by=10))/sd(y0)
increments
# [1]  4.5521432  2.7751960  0.9982488 -0.7786983 -2.5556455
# [6] -4.3325927
newTicks   <- mean(y2) - increments*sd(y2)
newTicks
# [1] -29.24281  68.06579 165.37438 262.68298 359.99158
# [6] 457.30017

# the bottom of the y axis in the plot is 4.55 sd's below y0's mean, 
#   thus the bottom of the new axis should be about -30, and the top of 
#   the new axis should be about 460

  axis(side=4, at=seq(0, 50, 10), labels=round(newTicks), col="green")
  legend("bottomleft", c("y0 (left axis)", "y1 (left axis)", 
         "y2 (right axis)"), pch=c(6, 18, 24), lty=1, 
         col=c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

[image]

All of this is a bit of a pain.  From @Carl Wittholf's answer, I gather the function `plotyy()` will do this for you automatically (I've never used it), but you will have to install (and subsequently load) the [pracma](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html) package first.